# Using DotNetOpenAuth to get both Contacts & Calendars from a Google account together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, dotnetopenauth

I am writing a web application using ASP.NET MVC3 (C#), and I need to get the calendars and contacts from my logged-in user's Google account(s).

Because I don't want to store the user's credentials, I am using OAuth (but not doing OpenID - I don't want my users to log in using their Google account).

I have the following code to get the access token and later use it to get the data:

```
var google = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumer.ServiceDescription, this.TokenManager);

// Is Google calling back with authorization?
var accessTokenResponse = google.ProcessUserAuthorization();
if (accessTokenResponse != null) {
    this.AccessToken = accessTokenResponse.AccessToken;
    //SAVE ACCESS TOKEN TO DATABASE
} else if (this.AccessToken == null) {
    // If we don't yet have access, immediately request it.
    GoogleConsumer.RequestAuthorization(google, GoogleConsumer.Applications.Contacts);
}
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, I'm only requesting authorization for the Contacts, and the `RequestAuthorization` method doesn't allow me to set more than one application.

How can I do it without the need for several different tokens for the different scopes? (One for Calendar, one for Contacts, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GoogleConsumer` class is provided as source code to you in the `DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock` project.  Please feel free to modify it to do just what you need.

Comment: Ok, so i need to modify that class.. now.. how i setup multiple scopes in the google uri authorization?

Answer (score 1):

Scopes can be placed in a string and separated by spaces

**EDIT: Added from poster's comments**

I use the following code when creating the scope `string`:

```
foreach (String s in Scopes) {
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0}", s));
}
scope = sb.ToString().Trim();
```

Where `Scopes` is an `array` of `Strings` (`String[]`) containing the scopes I want to use. When you request authorization from Google, then, you will see the list of services being requested displayed on the login screen.

Comment: This would be a more helpful answer if you provided some example code, and perhaps a deeper explanation of why it is relevant to the poster's question.

Comment: I use the following code when creating the scope string

    foreach ( String s in Scopes)
    {
     sb.Append(String.Format("{0} ",s));
    }
    scope = sb.ToString().Trim();


Where Scopes is an array of strings containing the scopes I want to use.

When you request authorization from Google you will see the list of services being requested in the login screen.